# binary tree with special property

Tags: algorithm, binary-tree

There is binary tree with special property that all its inner node have val = 'N' and all leaves have val = 'L'. Given its preorder. construct the tree and return the root node.

every node can either have two children or no child

Comment: What problem are you having?  What have you attempted so far?

Comment: Is this problem that you can't solve, or just problem for community members?

Comment: This problem is not as localized as one might think (I am assuming that is the reason for the downvote?).

Answer (score 5):

Recursion is your friend.

```
Tree TreeFromPreOrder(Stream t) {

    switch (t.GetNext()) {

        case Leaf: return new LeafNode;

        case InternalNode:
            Node n = new Node;

            n.Left = TreeFromPreOrder(t);
            n.Right = TreeFromPreOrder(t);
            return n;

        default:
            throw BadPreOrderException;
    }
}
```

Looking at it as a recursive method, it becomes easy to see how do other things.

For instance, say we wanted to print the InOrder traversal. The code will look something like this:

```
void PrintInorderFromPreOrder(Stream t) {

    Node n = new Node(t.GetNext());

    switch (n.Type) {

        case Leaf: return;

        case InternalNode:

            PrintInorderFromPreOrder(t);

            print(n.Value);

            PrintInorderFromPreOrder(t);

        default:
            throw BadPreOrderException;
    }
}
```

Also, I would like to mention that this is not that artificial. This type of representation can actually be used to save space when we need to serialize a binary tree: [Efficient Array Storage for Binary Tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2675756/efficient-array-storage-for-binary-tree/2676849#2676849).

Comment: that's better than my algorithm, because it clearly exploit the fact that the two subtrees of each internal node are listed one after the other. +1

Comment: @aka: Thanks, your answer is nice too. +1. Having a recursive viewpoint helps in doing other things too... See my edit.

Answer (score 1):

Just the basic idea: keep a stack where the head is the "current" node and read sequentially the string representing the preorder.

Now, if you encounter a 'L', then it means the "current" node has as a child a leaf, so you can "switch" to the right child and resuming building the corresponding subtree, pushing the root of that subtree; if, when encountering a 'L', the "current node" has already two children, pop an element from the stack.