# loading binary tree from string (parent-left-right)

Tags: java, tree

I have a binary tree that looks like this

[image]

the object that represents it looks like this (java)

```
 public class node {
   private String value = "";
   private TreeNode aChild;
   private TreeNode bChild;
 ....
 }
```

I want to read the data and build the tree from a string.
So I wrote some small method to serialize it and I have it like this
(parent-left-right)
0,null,O@1,left,A@2,left,C@3,left,D@4,left,E@4,right,F@1,right,B@

Then I read it and I have it as a  list - objects in this order O,A,C,D,E,F,B

And now my question is - how to I build the tree?
iterating and putting it on a stack, queue ?
should I serialize on a different order ?

(basically I want to learn the best practices for building a tree from string data)
can you refer me to a link on that subject ?

Answer (score 0):

Given your second string representation, there is no way to retrieve the original tree. So unless *any* tree with that sequence is acceptable, you'll have to include mor information in your string. One possible way would be representing `null` references in some fashion. Another would be using parentheses or similar.

Given your first representation, restoring the data is still possible. One algorithm expliting the level information would be the following:

- Maintain a reference *x* to the current position in your tree
- For every node *n* you want to add, move that reference *x* up in your tree as long as the level of *x* is no less than the level of *n*
- Check that now the level of *x* is exactly one less than the level of *n*
- Make *x* the parent of *n*, and *n* the next child of *x*
- Move *x* to now point at *n*

This works if you have *parent links* in your nodes. If you don't, then you can maintain a list of the most recent node for every level. *x* would then correspond to the last element of that list, and moving *x* up the tree would mean removing the last element from the list. The level of *x* would be the length of the list.

Answer (score 0):

Your serialization is not well explained, especially regarding how you represent missing nodes. There are several ways, such as representing the tree structure with ()s or by using the binary tree in an array technique.  Both of these can be serialized easily.  Take a look at [Efficient Array Storage for Binary Tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2675756/efficient-array-storage-for-binary-tree) for further explanations.